Show that if $(\Phi,\Psi)$ is a Craig pair, then both $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are synctactically consistent
I'm working through Mathematical Logic by Ian Chiswell and Wilfrid Hodges. And I'm stuck at exercise 3.10.2a

Let σ and τ be signatures. Suppose $\Phi$ is a set of formulas of LP($\sigma$) and $\Psi$ is a set of formulas of LP($\tau$). We say that $(\Phi,\Psi)$ is a Craig pair if there is no formula $\theta$ of LP($\sigma\cap\tau$) such that $\Phi\vdash_\sigma \theta$ and $\Psi\vdash_\tau \neg\theta$.
(a) Show that if $(\Phi,\Psi)$ is a Craig pair, then both $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are synctactically consistent

This is my attempt:
Assume that $(\Phi,\Psi)$ is Craig pair.
We proceed by contradiction and assume that at least one of $\Phi$ or $\Psi$ is syntactically inconsistent, say $\Phi$.
Then $\Phi\vdash_\sigma \perp$ and since we can derive anything from $\perp$, we have $\Phi\vdash_\sigma\theta$, where $\theta$ is a formula of LP($\sigma\cap\tau)$.
I don't know how to continue from here.
I can't find a formula $\neg\theta$ that I can derive from $\Psi$.
Also what happens when LP($\sigma\cap\tau)$ is empty?

Please define the notation LP.

@JeanAbouSamra LP stands for "Language of Propositions"

You're on the right track.
Hints
Choose a tautology, $\theta$, which is a formula of $LP$ for any signature. To ensure this, $\theta$ shouldn't contain any occurrences of propositional symbols. Then, $\theta$ is a formula of $LP(\sigma\cap\tau)$. So is $\neg\theta$. Since $\theta$ is a tautology, it's derivable from any set of formulas. Its derivation is independent of the signature because $\theta$ is. So, you have $\Psi\vdash_{\tau}\theta $. Since $\Phi$ is syntactically inconsistent, you have $\Phi\vdash_{\sigma}\neg\theta$. This implies the contradiction.
What happens when $\sigma\cap\tau$ is empty?
This doesn't affect the proof. The proof covers this case. You have chosen a $\theta$ which is a formula of LP for any signature. So, this includes the empty signature. The formulas of $LP(\emptyset)$ are built from $\bot$ and truth function symbols. But, they contain no occurrences of propositional symbols. This suggests a choice for $\theta$.
I hope this helps. Let me know if you want me to write a proof.
Edit: I'll write a proof now since you've had time to try the hints. So, read no further if you still want to try and prove it yourself.
Proof.
Let $\sigma$ and $\tau$ be signatures, $\Phi$ a set of formulas of $LP(\sigma)$, and $\Psi$ a set of formulas of $LP(\tau)$. Suppose that $(\Phi , \Psi)$ is a Craig pair and that one of the sets of formulas, say, $\Phi$, is syntactically inconsistent. Since $\bot$ is a formula of $LP(\rho)$ for any signature $\rho$, $\bot$ is a formula of $LP(\sigma\cap\tau)$. Since $\bot$ is a formula of $LP(\sigma\cap\tau)$, so is $\neg\bot$. Since $\Phi$ is syntactically inconsistent, $\Phi\vdash_{\sigma}\bot$. Since $\vdash_{\tau}\neg\bot$, $\Psi\vdash_{\tau}\neg\bot$. This implies a contradiction because $(\Phi , \Psi)$ is a Craig pair. Therefore, $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are syntactically consistent. $\square$
